# PHP MYSQL Insert Data in Arabic Language hashed

Tags: php, mysql, api, utf-8, arabic

I have mysql database 5.2.6 charset utf8/utf8_general_Ci and i want to insert arabic words. They aren't inserted correctly with the words hashed 
php code.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mun_app") or die ("could not connect database"); 
$input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$data = json_decode($input, true); 
$message = array(); 
if($data['action'] == "insert"){
    $subject =  $data['subject']; 
    $body = $data['body'];  

    $q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `Complaints` ( `subject` , `body`, `Date`) VALUES ('$subject', '$body',CURDATE())"); 

}
echo mysqli_error($con); 
?>
```

Comment: MySQL never released any 5.2 version.  Check again, preferably with `SELECT @@version;`

Answer (score 1):

Two queries:

```
   mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
   mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

got executed before connection is established. You can put them after `mysqli_connect` and change to use created connection. Like:

```
   mysqli_query($con, "set character_set_server='utf8'");
   mysqli_query($con, "set names 'utf8'");
```

Also, be sure to check that incoming values of $subject and $body are correct.

Comment: thanks alot for your anser 
and i,m sorry i want to vote you but show me this message
'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are'

Comment: Glad that helped you. You can just mark this answer as correct one, no need to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a UTF8 encoding/collation on the tables and columns you want to add UTF8 data to.
Second Use statements for INSERT in DB:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$data = json_decode($input, true); 
$message = array(); 
if($data['action'] == "insert"){
    $subject =  $data['subject']; 
    $body = $data['body'];  

$q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `Complaints` ( `subject` , `body`, `Date`) VALUES (?, ?,?)"); 
$date=CURDATE();
$q->bind_param("sss",$subject,$body,$date);
$q->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` API calls.

Do *not* use the `mysql_*` API at all!

"not correctly" -- Do you have some sample output?  See this for likely garbage and their causes.